# PHP - Most efficient way to extract substrings based on given delimiter?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string that contains some values I need to extract.  Each of these values is surrounded by a common character.

What is the most efficient way to extract all of these values into an array?

For example, given the following string:

```
stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%
```

I would like to get an array containing `value1` and `value2`

Comment: Most efficient in terms of memory or CPU time? Most efficient in PHP?..

Comment: Why did this question get a negative vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$s = "stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%";
preg_match_all('~%(.+?)%~', $s, $m);
$values = $m[1];
```

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%';
$string = trim( $string, '%' ); 
$array = explode( '%' , $string );
```

Comment: incorrect: `array(4) { [0]=> string(15) "stackoverflowis" [1]=> string(6) "value1" [2]=> string(13) "butyouarevery" [3]=> string(6) "value2" }`

Comment: @k102 it is much more efficient to read each even item from array, then to hope that there will be % at the end of string , and not at the start.

Comment: @tereško i don't agree. how can you tell that `$array[1]` is one of needed strings and `$array[0]` not? all i want to say - your answer is not full

Comment: @k102 do you not see that your own code has the same problem ? what if string is `"stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2"` ? or `"%stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%"` ?

Comment: @tereško my code works on given string. yours - is only a part of a code.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to explode. Like $array = explode('%', $string);

LE:

```
<?php

$s = 'stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%';
$a = explode('%', $s);
$a = array_filter($a, 'strlen'); // removing NULL values
$last = ''; // last value inserted;
for($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++)
    if (isset($a[$i+1]) && $a[$i] <> $last)
        $t[] = $last = $a[$i+1];

echo '<pre>'; print_r($t); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: explode wouldn't extract values, it'll just split string into array

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%";
preg_match_all('/%([a-z0-9]+)%/',$str,$m);
var_dump($m[1]);

array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "value1" [1]=> string(6) "value2" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` and take the odd-indexed values from the resulting array. You indicated you wanted the most efficient method, and this will be faster than a regex solution.

```
$str = 'stackoverflowis%value1%butyouarevery%value2%';
$arr = explode('%', $str);

$ct = count($arr);

for ($i = 1; $i < $ct; $i += 2) {
    echo $arr[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/%([^%]+)%/', $s, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```